# Generic List to EntitySet Conversion

Tags: c#, linq, entityset

How do I Convert a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` to a `System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<T>` ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't think you can convert a `List<T>` to an `EntitySet<T>` but you can put the content of your list in the entitySet.

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var entitySet = new EntitySet<string>();
entitySet.AddRange(list);
```

Here's a extension method for that:

```
public static EntitySet<T> ToEntitySet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class
{
    var es = new EntitySet<T>();
    es.AddRange(source);
    return es;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
var list = new List<string> 
{ 
    "element1", "element2" 
};
var entitySet = new EntitySet<string>();
entitySet.AddRange(list);
```