# observableCollection to EntitySet

Tags: c#, observablecollection, entityset

How do I assign a  `observableCollection<T>` into a `EntitySet<T>` ?

Comment: Have you tried using the same approach as for your nearly identical question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848680

Comment: Yes I did but the problem is when ever I add each item using foreach loop it doesn't update my Datagrid.